# Using the group role from the current user session AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to use the group IAM role from current user session rather than the auth role of a user?

I am getting my current user session and instantiating a new `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` service with this session like so:

```
const currentCredentials = await $Amplify.Auth.currentCredentials();
`const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(currentCredentials);`
```

This uses the auth role rather than the group the user is in, I don't see an option to pass the roleARN in as a param to the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the settings in Identity pool rather than user pool. Edit Identity pool and select Authentication providers. Here you can ask cognito to select the role from token.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!! I've been searching for this answer for hours.